# Open jaw return on Virgin Atlantic website

Tags: air-travel, open-jaw, virgin-atlantic

I'm looking to buy an open jaw return ticket LHR->JFK, then BOS->LHR (London-New York, then Boston-London) on Virgin Atlantic, however I can't seem to find such option on their website. Am I missing something or is it simply not available?

Comment: Sometimes you either have to call the airline or go through a travel agent

Comment: If I look this route up on skyscanner (or other comparison websites) using multi city routes, I can see several options for this route using VA airlines, so I would either call them up directly, or book via a third party if you only want to book onlie.

Comment: @Uciebila That looks like an answer :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question, as the result is useful. The reason I wanted to buy online was that VA used to charge an extra fee for phone bookings (not too sure if they still do) - and I wanted to avoid it.

I ended up calling Virgin Atlantic, who confirmed that this option is not available on their website and needs to be booked over the phone.  They also would not charge a fee, because in this case phone booking is the only option.  As an added bonus I found out that I actually had enough air miles to pay for the ticket - so the whole thing turned out to be much cheaper than I was prepared to pay.